# Aggregate functions with DISTINCT cannot be used with arguments of type STRUCT

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to do a count of distinct which normally works but its not working with Big Query.
Query:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "select A.ID,
COUNT(distinct(A.SALES_ORDER_NUM)) AS SALES_ORDER_NUM_COUNT,
COUNT(distinct(A.SALES_ORDER_NUM, A.ODR_ITEM)) AS ORDER_ITM_NUM_COUNT,
from table A
GROUP BY 1;"
```

Error:

```
Error in query string: Error processing job 'wmt-edw-sandbox:bqjob_r4d217f5951748eb5_00000188dc0de701_1': Aggregate functions with DISTINCT cannot be used with arguments of type STRUCT at [4:1]
```

What can be the possible solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to count distinct. Use the below query to retrieve data without error : -

```
SELECT
  A.ID,
  COUNT(DISTINCT A.SALES_ORDER_NUM) AS SALES_ORDER_NUM_COUNT,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(A.SALES_ORDER_NUM, A.ODR_ITEM)) AS ORDER_ITM_NUM_COUNT
FROM
  table_name AS A
GROUP BY
  A.ID;
```